# Symfony2 + JS Timeline. How to pass a json file to a view?

Tags: symfony, timeline

A Symfony2 newbie question.

I wish to use Simile's Timeline http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/ with my Symfony2 web application.
To do so, I need to output a .json file and to pass it to a JS code within my timeline.html.twig  view:

```
...
tl.loadJSON("http://localhost:{{ <my json file> }}?"+ (new Date().getTime()), function(json, url) {...}
```

I am able to output a .json file using a json.html.twig template + a jsonAction controller

```
 /**
 * Lists all Post entities.
 *
 * @Route("/json", name="Mario_Post_json")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
  public function jsonAction()
{
$response = new Response();
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$query = $this->getDoctrine()
       ->getRepository('MarioBlogBundle:Post')
       ->createQueryBuilder('e')
       ->getQuery();

$results = $query->getArrayResult();    

$response->setContent(json_encode($results));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  return $response;
}
```

I am able to load and render a static .json file by:

```
tl.loadJSON("http://localhost{{ asset('bundles/marioblog/js/timeline/timeline.json') }}?"+ (new Date().getTime()), function(json, url) {...}
```

But if I try variants of something like

```
tl.loadJSON("http://localhost/symfony/web/app_dev.php/Mario/Post/jsonout?"+ (new Date().getTime()), function(json, url) {...}
```

it always fails.
Help is welcome.

Comment: I think JSON is fetched after you template is rendered(after twig job). So you need to perform JSON fetching at the javascript level (for example by sending an AJAX request that executes your PHP controller).PS: its a newbie remark.

Comment: My understanding is that tl.loadJSON is at the JS level, isn't it?

Comment: Can you please show us : how does your JS code executes your PHP controller? I unfortunately still cannot see it in your code.

Comment: I am not sure. For a static myfile.json file, Simile's code just requires to write  tl.loadJSON("<path>/myfile.json?"+ (..), function(json, url) {  eventSource.loadJSON(json, url);});

Answer (score 0):

I feel the approach is like this:

```
function ajaxCall()
{

    $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: // URL for the PHP controller,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data){

               // give the data (a JSON in your case) to the Simile's  js function
            }
                    });  

}
```

Note: This is AJAX using jQuery. You can use any other javascript library or even raw javascript to perform AJAX.

Good luck

Comment: I am not sure. I'll do some homework, and be back. thks anyway.